# javascript for loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Issue I am having is as follows: This for loop should be putting a number in the address and counting up to 152 and then putting it full address as follows

```
<img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/1.png">
<img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/2.png">
```

and so on. What am I missing?

```js
var webaddress = ['<img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/">'];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 152; i++) {
  text += webaddress[i] + ".png";
}
document.getElementById("Pokeman").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" type="script" href="script.jss"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>

</head>


<body>
  <div id="container">

    <p id="Pokeman"></p>



  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the webaddress as root string and replace it inside loop

```js
var webaddress = '<img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/[index].png">';
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 152; i++) {
    text += webaddress.replace("[index]", i);
    }
    document.write(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your javascript in the head - but the element that is referenced (#Pokeman) is not in the DOM yet - simply move the js block to the end - before the closing body tag. and since you are using jquery - i simplified the js and used it too.

EDIT - I just inserted your img code into the function so that it will render the images as the number increments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p id="Pokeman"></p>
    </div>
    
  <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" type="script" href="script.jss"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script> 
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 152; i++) {
       $("#Pokeman").append('<img src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/'+ i + '.png"/>');
     }
   })
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well this printed :) Now i need to find out why its undefined

Comment: that would be because webaddress only has one value but you are incrementing to 152. - also you will need to append the .png to the image url before the closing tag

Comment: EDIT - I just inserted your img code into the function so that it will render the images as the number increments.